# How can I delete lines fit a pattern to a register or a new file?

Tags: register, global-command, multiple-lines

I can use the powerful `:g` command to delete lines that contain a certain pattern like  this:

```
:g/^\va pattern/d
```

I thought I should paste the deleted content to a new place but I cannot find all those lines that have been removed by checking the registers:

```
:register
```

The `"` register only remembered the one line of them which I thought would only be the last line deleted.

Can I gather all the deleted lines in one register and use them elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

#### Use a Dedicated Register to Which You Append

Note `delete` overwrites the unnamed register `""` for each match. Therefore, only the last line matching the pattern is still available in `""`. Also the numbered registers `"0-"9` are not helpful because there are only 10 of them. However, you can append each line to one of the named registers `"a-"z`:

`:h quote_alpha`:

> 4. Named registers `"a` to `"z` or `"A` to `"Z`           `*quote_alpha*` `*quotea*`
>      Vim fills these registers only when you say so.  Specify them as lowercase
>      letters to replace their previous contents **or as uppercase letters to append
>      to their previous contents.**

The steps would be

1. Clear target register by `qaq` (here illustrated for `"a`)
2. Find lines matching a pattern, append line to register `"a` when deleting the line (use capitalized letter for appending instead of overwriting)

   ```
   :g/^\va pattern/d A
   ```
3. Paste at new location with `"ap`

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Hotschke's answer above, once all the lines of interest are in a register ("a" in this example), here's how to write the contents to a file:

```
:new filename | $put a | x
```

[Write register contents to file](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Write-register-contents-to-file-td5610081.html)